# Programmatically enumerate symbols in a dynamic library on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, symbols, nm

I need a way to enumerate symbols and their addresses exported from dylibs on Mac OS X.

From the shell I would normally use `nm` for this - is there a library which I can use from my code to get the same things that `nm` provides? Similar to the dbghelp API on Windows.

As a last resort I suppose I could spawn `nm` and parse the output but I'm keen to avoid this if there is a cleaner method.

Comment: It looks like it's quite complicated on OSX.  You can see the source code for `nm` [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/cctools-622.5.1/misc/nm.c)

Comment: Same as above for this: http://code.google.com/p/macdependency/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nm (and otool) have the knowledge built into them rather than using an API. The best you will get is header files defining the file format (see 'man Mach-O'). I would invoke nm and parse the output; there's nothing wrong with reusing an existing component just because the interface is program execution rather than function call.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear but an answer nonetheless!